# С помощью каких технологий можно сделать локальный сервер на питоне?

Tags: python, reactjs

У меня есть приложение на Реакт, а точнее на typesctipt, в котором можно сохранять картинки и музыку.

Проблема в том, что насколько я понимаю, файлы музыки нельзя сохранять локально в браузере. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать свой сервер, в котором я смогу хранить все файлы, которые мне нужны.

Мне бы хотелось сделать его на Питон - с помощью каких технологий можно это сделать?

Comment: django/flask могут стартовать сервер.

Comment: `socket`, `flask`, `cgi`, `django`, `bottle`, `wsgi` ...

Comment: @andreymal аплоад нужен наверное

Comment: @eri ах да, на фразу «можно сохранять» внимания не обратил

Comment: вообще я бы хотел сделать какой нибудь простой сервер на flask из которого я просто буду брать все сохраненные файлы, но сижу уже почти час и не могу найти каких то хороших материалов, везде гайды про то как сделать приложение на flask, хотя по факту у меня оно уже есть, просто нужен сервер

Comment: @Bad_m читайте материалы и просто не используйте то что вам не требуется

Comment: https://ngrok.io

Comment: @694201970 дорого, http://127.1:8080/ бесплатно и безлимитно

Answer (score 1):

[Вот пример из документации по aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#file-uploads), дополненный для самодостаточности:

```
from aiohttp import web
import os

async def form(request):
    return web.Response(text="""<html>
        <form action="/store/mp3" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="mp3">Mp3</label>
        <input id="mp3" name="mp3" type="file" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form></html>""", content_type='text/html')

async def store_mp3_handler(request):
    reader = await request.multipart()

    # /!\ Don't forget to validate your inputs /!\

    # reader.next() will `yield` the fields of your form

    field = await reader.next()
    assert field.name == 'mp3'
    filename = field.filename
    # You cannot rely on Content-Length if transfer is chunked.
    size = 0

    with open(os.path.join('mp3/', filename), 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = await field.read_chunk()  # 8192 bytes by default.
            if not chunk:
                break
            size += len(chunk)
            f.write(chunk)

    return web.Response(text='''
        {} sized of {} successfully stored in
        <a href="/mp3">/mp3/</a>'''.format(filename, size),
        content_type='text/html')


os.makedirs('mp3/', exist_ok=True)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.static('/mp3', 'mp3/', show_index=True)])
app.add_routes([web.get('/', form)])
app.add_routes([web.post('/store/mp3', store_mp3_handler)])

web.run_app(app)
```

Установить aiohttp:

```
python3 -m pip install aiohttp
```

А просто раздать папку на питоне можно без кода и дополнительных библиотек

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Comment: ух, для человека который не занимался back-end много новой информации, но придется во всем разобраться, чтобы повысить свой уровень знаний. Спасибо за документацию)